# Passing multiple parameter in OpenWithParm in Powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

Here are the codes for passing single parameter in another pb window object.

in `dw_header` clicked event

```
long ll_customer
datetime dt_from, dt_to
ll_customer = getitemnumber(1,"customer_id")
dt_from = datetime(date(f_today()),time('00:00:00'))
dt_to = datetime(date(f_today()),time('23:59:59.99'))

openwithparm(w_customer_balance,ll_customer)
```

in `w_customer_balance` open event

```
long ll_id
datetime dt_from, dt_to
ll_id = message.doubleparm
dw_1.settransobject(sqlca)
dw_1.retrieve(ll_id)
```

This perfectly working fine in passing single parameter.
But i want to pass another parameters  w/c are `dt_from` and `dt_to` to a to customer balance window.

Anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pass multiple parameters, you can use the following this method:

The definition of structural variables: lstr_declaredstr, which includes you want to pass the parameters:

Variable type variable name:

ID Unsignedlong; Name Character; Email Character; Homepage Character

... ...

Calling script, use the following code:

```
lstr_declaredstr lstr_parmtotrans
lstr_parmtotrans.id = 1
lstr_paramtotrans.name = "panya"
lstr_paramtotrans.email = "panya@163.net"
lstr_paramtotrans.homepage = "http://panya.163.net"
```

...

```
openwithparm (w_wantparm, lstr_paramtotrans)
```

Then open the window in the w_wantparm the open case, to obtain structural information:

```
lstr_declaredstr lstr_getparm
integer li_getid
string ls_getname
string ls_getemail
string ls_gethomepage
lstr_getparm = message.powerobjectparm
li_getid = lstr_getparm.id
ls_getname = lstr_getparm.name
ls_geemail = lstr_getparm.email
ls_gethomepage = lstr_getparm.homepage
```

For more examples, in this web: [web](http://tutorialsto.com/software/power-builder/powerbuilder-window-transmission-between-the-multi-parameter-approach.html)

Comment: Do I need to create structure named lstr_declaredstr?

Comment: Yes, create structure. Is an option for the passage of parameters

Comment: And then also in w_wantparm i need to create lstr_declaredstr structure?

Comment: You can use this too: lstr_declaredstr   lstr_getparm

Comment: not working :( its says "cannot assign object of type structure to variable.."

Comment: Sorry to say that I can not find error in my code, remember: "lstr_declaredstr" is a structure. Here's a web with a visual example, I hope it helps: http://www.mytechlogy.com/IT-blogs/13306/messageobject-for-comunication-between-windows-in-powerbuilder-using-structures/

Answer (score 1):

You can also define a non-visual object with instance variables which you set then pass with an Openwithparm method call.  The called window would have to have the nvo created (normally as an instance variable) and then 'received' in the open event via the powerobjectparm parameter type.

Comment: i dont understand a thing :D. Sorry im a bit new to powerbuilder. Can you provide samples?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Matt Balent, instead of defining a structure specially for passing some parameters to a window, you can create a dedicated object passed to `OpenWithParm()` and that can be retrieved in the `open()` with `message.powerobjectparm` (because you can pass any powerobject to this method).

By extension, you can create a generic object type that can receive an arbitrary number of named parameters of `any` type that you can get by their name in the `open()` event in a way similar as the structure. A kind of poor man's dictionary.

Here is an exemple based on some existing code:

- the `nv_va_arg` object (like C's variable arguments type) - the source is copied from the object "edit source" context menu, to recreate the object, add a new "custom class" object named `nv_va_args`, save it then right-click "edit source" and paste the following code:

```
      forward
      global type nv_va_args from nonvisualobject
      end type
      end forward

      global type nv_va_args from nonvisualobject autoinstantiate
      end type

      type variables

      private:
      string _is_names[]
      any _ia_items[]

      end variables
      forward prototypes
      public subroutine add_item (string as_name, any aa_val)
      private function integer search (string as_name)
      public subroutine set_item (string as_name, any aa_val)
      public function any get_item (string as_name)
      private subroutine set_item (integer ai_index, string as_name, any aa_val)
      public function integer size ()
      public function string get_name (integer ai_index)
      public function any get_item (integer ai_index)
      end prototypes

      public subroutine add_item (string as_name, any aa_val);
      /* add a new item if not already present */

      int idx

      idx = search(as_name)
      if idx = -1 then
            idx = upperbound(_is_names) + 1
            set_item(idx, as_name, aa_val)
      end if

      end subroutine

      private function integer search (string as_name);
      /* search for an item */

      int i, n
      n = upperbound(_is_names)

      for i = 1 to n
            if _is_names[i] = as_name then return i
      next

      return -1

      end function

      public subroutine set_item (string as_name, any aa_val);
      /* public setter */
      int idx

      idx = search(as_name)
      if idx =-1 then
            idx = upperbound(_is_names) + 1
      end if
      set_item(idx, as_name, aa_val)

      end subroutine

      public function any get_item (string as_name);
      /* get the named item */

      int idx
      any la_val

      idx = search(as_name)
      if idx > 0 then
            la_val = _ia_items[idx]
      end if

      return la_val

      end function

      private subroutine set_item (integer ai_index, string as_name, any aa_val);
      /* internal setter */

      _is_names[ai_index] = as_name
      _ia_items[ai_index] = aa_val

      end subroutine

      public function integer size ();
      /* return the number of elements */
      return upperbound(_is_names)

      end function

      public function string get_name (integer ai_index);
      /* return the name of the nth item */

      string ls_ret = ""
      if ai_index > 0 and ai_index <= upperbound(_is_names) then
            ls_ret = _is_names[ai_index]
      end if

      return ls_ret

      end function

      public function any get_item (integer ai_index);
      /* get the named item */

      any la_val

      if ai_index > 0 and ai_index <= upperbound(_is_names) then
            la_val = _ia_items[ai_index]
      end if

      return la_val

      end function

      on nv_va_args.create
      call super::create
      TriggerEvent( this, "constructor" )
      end on

      on nv_va_args.destroy
      TriggerEvent( this, "destructor" )
      call super::destroy
      end on
```

- an example of parameter filling, you can use any name and any type that will be stored in the internal `any` array of `nv_va_args` object:

```
        nv_va_args lva_args

        //set some values
        lva_args.add_item("arg_1", 42)
        lva_args.add_item("arg_2", "foo bar")

        //change a value
        lva_args.set_item("arg_2", "foo baz")

        openwithparm(w_test, lva_args)
```

- 2 examples of arguments retrieving, put in the `open()` event of the window. Note that the object retrieval from the `message` object must be done at the beginning of the event for not loosing its value (the `message` object is a global object that can be overwritten quite rapidly)

```
        powerobject lpo_arg //do not create it, as it is autoinstanciated
        lpo_arg = message.PowerObjectParm //make immediate copy of the message
        nv_va_args lva_args

        if isvalid(lpo_arg) and not isnull(lpo_arg) then
            lva_args = lpo_arg
        end if

        //example: enumerate all the parameters
        string ls_msg = "", ls_class
        int i
        any la_val
        for i = 1 to lva_args.size()
            ls_msg = ls_msg + lva_args.get_name(i) + ': '
            la_val = lva_args.get_item(i)
            ls_class = classname(la_val)
            if ls_class = "string" or ls_class = "long" then
                ls_msg = ls_msg + string(la_val, "[general]")
            else
                ls_msg = ls_msg + '[' + ls_class + ']'
            end if
            ls_msg = ls_msg + "~r~n"
        next
        messagebox("list of parameters", ls_msg)

        //example: just get a named parameter
        string ls_name = "arg_2"
        la_val = lva_args.get_item(ls_name)
        ls_msg = ls_name + " is " + string(la_val, "[general]")
        messagebox("named parameter", ls_msg)
```

Comment: Why downvote? My answer is perfectly suitable for the question asked.